# XML validation with an external DTD in Java

Tags: java, xml, dtd

How can I test an xml string to see if it validates against and dtd file?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096365/validate-an-xml-file-against-local-dtd-file-with-java) but they only see to be talking about replacing the dtd declaration on an xml file.

Person.DTD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT person (id)>
<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
```

Test

```
@Test
public void should_serialize_a_shootout_to_xml_and_validate_against_a_dtd(){
    String xml = "<person><id>12</id></person>";        
    Assert.assertTrue(validate_xml("person.dtd",xml));
}

boolean validate_xml(String dtd_filename,String xml){
    //check xml and throw validation errors
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: this question is answered over here: [Validate an XML file against local DTD file with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096365/validate-an-xml-file-against-local-dtd-file-with-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate an XML file against local DTD file with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096365/validate-an-xml-file-against-local-dtd-file-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

I may come back later with some code, but here's the procedure that springs to my mind:

1. Wrap string with StringReader
2. Create validating SAX parser
3. Parse file, have SAX handler track number of error instances
4. Valid if zero errors