# Validate XML file

Tags: java, xml, validation

I have an XML file not valid, like this:
Example:

```
<projects>
  <project id =BP001>
   <name>Banking Project</name>
   <start-date>Jan 10 1999</start-date>
   <end-date>Jan 10 2003</end-date>
</project>
```

project id =BP001 ==> project id ="BP001"

It must be like that allover the file.
I'm using java and I want to do this to validate the file
Any idea?

Comment: Searching your title on Google leads me to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362926/xml-syntax-validation-in-java

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "like that"? Also, wouldn't you rather fix the source that produces these invalid files instead of cleaning up that mess afterwards?

Comment: @TimPietzcker - he may not have that option; this could be produced from a business partner.

Answer (score 1):

You describe it as an "XML file, not valid". It's better to think of it as a file that isn't XML. If you want to process files that aren't XML, then you'll need non-XML tools. In particular, you will need a parser that can handle the grammar to which these files conform. That means (a) you'll have to define this grammar, and (b) you'll have to write a parser for it.

This is a lot of work, and this is why using XML is a good thing; it means that people don't have to write their own parsers. Using something that's similar to XML but not actually XML means you don't get any of these benefits.