# How to determine whether a given file is an xml valide file

Tags: java, xml

How to determine whether a given file is an xml valide file in JAVA?

for example  :

```
bool valide = IsAnXMLFile(new File("file.txt"));
```

Thank's.

Comment: You mean valid as *well formed* or as *valid according to a schema*?

Comment: If you want to check against an XML-Schema check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file

Comment: try to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362926/xml-syntax-validation-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean valide(String filename) throws JDOMException, IOException
{ 
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();  
        try{
                 Document doc = builder.build(new File(filename));     
               } catch (JDOMParseException ex) {
                 return false;
                }
         return true;
}
```

Comment: That's only the validation if a DTD is specified in the document or if the doctype is specified inline. For schema-based validation see above.

Comment: excessive amounts of unneeded try/catch statements will slow down the system considerably.

Answer (score 1):

you can check well-formedness just by loading the file with a parser. if the file references a dtd then it is also validated against this dtd (this requires the dtd to be present at the specified place). If you use a schema language (f.i. xsd) then you need to validate the file manually when loading it. JAXP is the keyword here!

Here is a small snippet for validation against a schema:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaLanguage.getId());
schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(getLSResourceResolver()); //optional

Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaURL)
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(...)));
```