# XML validation using dtd

Tags: java, xml, dom, dtd

I am using the following snippet to write an XML file. I need to throw an exception if the document is not valid one. How can I do validation in this piece of code?

```
private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    tf.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(4));
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "schema.dtd");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(file)));
}
```

Comment: this may be some help for u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096365/validate-an-xml-file-against-local-dtd-file-with-java

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the EntityResolver, checkout [this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipent/index.html).