# Validate xml document against external DTD

Tags: java, xml, sax, dtd, saxparser

I need to validate external XML document against DTD, that's stored in my jar. But the problem is, that this document probably don't have `<!DOCTYPE` declaration. So, I can't just setEntityResolver.

I'm using SAXParserFactory, because this document might be very large.
I have figured out how to do it with XSD - I simply create a new Schema and then set it to SAXParserFactory. But this approach don't work with DTD.

But I definitely need to do that with DTD, not XSD. Because DTD is pretty complex and it's not trivial to convert it to XSD.

So, is there a way?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096365/validate-an-xml-file-against-local-dtd-file-with-java)

Comment: @npe, Hm. Seems that solution with transformation sucks. Because it'll create a new document in-memory.