# How to reference online DTD for my XML parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, dtd

How can I reference online or external DTD in my XML in C#?

> ```
>     string fileName = @"C:\\temp\H2009.xml";
>
>     XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
>
>     xDoc.Load(fileName);
> ```

My DTD file is **ftp.myPartnerCompany.com/Name.ent**

In this .ent file, they define entity like that

```
<!ENTITY Acaron "&#258;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with caron (breve),                                  
                                  U+0102 Latin Extended-A -->


<!ENTITY acaron "&#259;"> <!-- latin small letter a with caron (breve),                                  
                                  U+0103 Latin Extended-A -->
<!ENTITY Acedil "&#260;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with cedilla,
                                  U+0104 Latin Extended-A -->
```

Now I got the problem like line below since I don't know how to link the **xml and .ent file**.

***Reference to undeclared entity 'Acaron '. Line 4971, position 21.***

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Forget to mention my XML file , it will be like that below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<MA>
<Y07 CLID='C737467' KW='BIRANT' KW2='ESINOGLU'>
       <Y0747>B&acaron;RANT ES&acaron;NO&Gcaron;LU</Y0747>
       <Y0748>MARK KO KYI Sok Kuulu&scedil; Sit
             KA&Gcaron;ITHASDNE/&Idot;THAILAND
       </Y0748>
<Y07>
<MA>
```

Comment: Check the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470313/net-how-to-validate-xml-file-with-dtd-without-doctype-declaration

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples in your question, the .ent file you're pointing to is not a DTD. There aren't any ELEMENT/ATTLIST declarations so the structure is not defined. Without a DTD, your XML can only be well formed (but it isn't).

To reference the file containing all of your ENTITY declarations, you need to use a parameter entity in a DOCTYPE declaration. I don't know C#, so I don't know exactly how you would code this so the output is correct, but here is an example of what your XML output should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE MA [
<!ENTITY % ents SYSTEM "name.ent">
%ents;
]>
<MA>
  <Y07 CLID="C737467" KW="BIRANT" KW2="ESINOGLU">
    <Y0747>B&acaron;RANT ES&acaron;NO&Gcaron;LU</Y0747>
    <Y0748>MARK KO KYI Sok Kuulu&scedil; Sit KA&Gcaron;ITHASDNE/&Idot;THAILAND </Y0748>
  </Y07>
</MA>
```

Hope this helps.